# ArgumentError in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to write some tree data structure in ruby. The class file:

```
class Tree
  attr_accessor :node, :left, :right
  def initialize(node, left=nil, right=nil)
    self.node=node
    self.left=left
    self.right=right
  end
end
```

The rspec file:

```
require 'init.rb'

describe Tree do
  it "should be created" do
    t2=Tree.new(2)
    t1=Tree.new(1)
    t=Tree.new(3,t1,t2)
    t.should_not be nil
    t.left.node should eql 1
    t.right.node should eql 2
  end
end
```

Rspec keeps complaining:

```
1) Tree should be created
     Failure/Error: t.left.node should eql 1
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
     # ./app/tree.rb:3:in `initialize'
     # ./spec/tree_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Why?? I move the spec code into the class file and it works out. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe it or not, the problem is two missing dots in your rspec. These lines:

```
t.left.node should eql 1
t.right.node should eql 2
```

should be this:

```
t.left.node.should eql 1
t.right.node.should eql 2
```

Insert that period before `should`, and your spec should pass.

Here's what's going on. The `should` method works on any value, but if you call it bare, like this:

```
should == "hello"
```

it will operate on the subject of your test. What's the subject? Well, you can set the subject to whatever you want using the `subject` method, but if you don't, rspec will assume the subject is an instance of whatever class is being described. It sees this at the top of your spec:

```
describe Tree
```

and tries to create a subject like this:

```
Tree.new
```

which blows up, since your `initialize` won't work without any arguments; it needs at least one. The result is a pretty cryptic error if you didn't intend to write a `should` with an implicit subject.

Comment: Thanks so much. Stupid me. The message is truly cryptic and a bit misguiding.... I was trying to figure out what was wrong with my initializer instead of double-check the spec itself.